# Applying knockout extenders after mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a problem with adding a knockout extender to observables after they have been created.  In the following example the extender is run on `foo` every time the value changes as expected but only once, when first called, for `bar`.

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.foo = ko.observable(1).extend({ numeric: 1 });

    self.bar = ko.observable(1);

    self.bar.extend({ numeric: 1 });
};
```

Essentially I am mapping a large JSON object and would like to add extenders after the mapping has occurred to some of the properties.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Below is a jsfiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/LgxTn/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you have is that **the extender is creating a new observable** (based on the observable it's extending). And that new observable is not being used in your second call to `extend`.

To fix this (without changing the code of the extender) you can **assign** the response from calling `extend` **into the same property it's called**.

In other words, add `self.bar =` in front of your last line in order to have this:

```
self.bar = self.bar.extend({ numeric: 1 });
```

Comment: This solution does not reacts on template re-rendering for sub-observables. Try this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html Live Example 2.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The OP and I based our code in that same `ko.extenders.numeric` posted on that documentation page. Please post a new answer if your approach is substantially different than mine.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstanding something but this does not work as expected, check it out http://jsfiddle.net/BqXed/

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. But I think for this specific problem the `numeric` extender does work well even when applied after mapping: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/LgxTn/5/. I also think I found out a solution to the `required` extender: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/LgxTn/8/ (calling `applyBindings` again)

Comment: calling `applyBindings` again will throw an exception for already binded elements. Btw thank you :)