# Knockout validation check process and working order ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am having a textbox binded with datepicker and i am applying knockout validation to it .

I need some clarification on how knockout does the Job of validation like for the textbox i have `Extended` required field validation first and some custom validation next to it .

My major concern is if knockout executes validation conditions even after 1st condition fails(required in mycase)  then i got a problem i.e i get NULL exceptions .

**Let me put this in example :**

```
    self.startDate.extend({required: true}),

    self.startDate.extend({
 // here i have some complex logic where i `split` date `(like self.startDate().split('/') )`  date and do the following .
    })
```

Onload my textbox will be empty with no date . is suppose complete validation check is done onload i get ERROR at split as `self.startDate().split('/')` where split is `undefined` due to no data in observable .

Things i need clarity on are :

- How validation check is done on load ?
- If onload complete validation check is done means anyway we can make Validations work in a sequential way i.e once 1st condition is done it should move to check next like that

Any suggestion are much appreciated .

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986262/applying-knockout-extenders-after-mapping

Comment: sadly no `sWWW` i am just looking for a case where will second validation condition executes even though condition one fails . i am hoping its like a `if/else` rather `if`

Comment: Typically there should be no two `self.startDate` with `extend` i need to make it in one set i am unable to do so .

Comment: So are you unable to have something like `self.startDate({require: true, extender2: doSomething})`

Comment: well i haven't tried that exactly but it was one in my whilst and most important thing is as you mentioned above in comment `self.startDate({require: true, extender2: doSomething})` will `extender2` does even excecute if `require:true` fails .

Answer (score 0):

finally got  what excatly i am looking for but in a complex and clumsy way which i want to avoid everytime

**My code :**

```
self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
                self.ForecastDateVM.extend({

required: { " enter something " },

validation: {validator: function (val, someOtherVal) {
                            if (val != undefined && someOtherVal() != undefined) {
                                var date1 = val.split('/'); 
                                var date2 = someOtherVal().split('/');

                            },
                            message: 'Must be greater ActualDate',
                            params: self.ActualDateVM
                        }
                    })
            ]);
```

*Things i got myself clarified by severe debugging stuff :-*

- Onload whatever we have inside `.extend({` those all gets checked up in a `sequential` success order  i.e if 1st condtion fails it wont check for 2nd inside extend .
- Point one made my work looks straight forward .

In short Knockout Validation works in **if/else** way .